# input result from one program file into another program in python

Tags: python

The first python program called first.py includes the following code:

```
print ('my name is viena')
```

How can I input the result from that first program, i.e., 'my name is viena' as input into my second program called second.py which includes the following code:

```
question = 'what\'s your name?'
answer = ?????HERE HOW TO INPUT THE RESULT FROM FIRST PROGRAM

print (answer)
my name is viena
```

Note: There should be two different python script files as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Create a function which ll return the value in file1. In file2, import file1 and call the function?

Comment: Don't put a space between `print` and `(...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can wrap the print statement in your first program inside a function (say `print_name`) , then you can so something like

```
import first
first.print_name()
```

to get the name.

For a completely general purpose solution that involves shelling out, take a look at the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about change the first script as importable module:

```
# Changed the print function call with function.
def my_name():
    return 'my name is viena'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(my_name())
```

Another script can now import the first script using `import` statement, and use its functions.

```
import name_of_the_first_script

question = "what's your name?"
answer = name_of_the_first_script.my_name()
```